How to customize a cube-shaped gizmo
I'm interested in gizmos. I saw that it was possible to create a custom gizmo, as shown in the gizmo_custom_geometry.py template. I want to try making a cube shaped gizmo. However, this does not produce the expected result.
I don't know how to tell blender to use 4 points per faces. The arguments to new_custom_shape are type and verts. Type being a string part of a defined list. Verts is a list of point coordinates.
How to customize a cube gizmo?
Do you have any documentation on gizmos in general?
What about custom gadgets?
